# Fazer modal box sem HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde,

Tenho este código que me gera um Modal Box, no entanto não está a funcionar:

```
jQuery(function() {

var modalHtml =
'<div id="open-modal" class="modal-window">' +
'  <div>' +
'    <a href="#" title="Close" class="modal-close">Close</a>' +
'    <h1>Voilà!</h1>' +
'    <div>A CSS-only modal based on the :target pseudo-class. Hope you find it helpful. <a href="#" target="_blank">Say hello on Twitter.</a></div>' +
'    </div>' +
'</div>';

  // insert HTML dynamically
  jQuery(".modal-dialog").html(modalHtml);

  // display
  jQuery(".modal-dialog").modal('show');

  // append a new element to the DOM
  jQuery('body').after('<div class="modal-dialog modal"></div>');

});;
```

O que poderei alterar para que ele funcione? Também queria que ao dar refresh na página que ele executasse sempre o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá a sequência de inserção do seu script esta **incorreta**.

```js
jQuery(function() {

var modalHtml =
'<div id="open-modal" class="modal-window">' +
'  <div>' +
'    <a href="#" title="Close" class="modal-close">Close</a>' +
'    <h1>Voilà!</h1>' +
'    <div>A CSS-only modal based on the :target pseudo-class. Hope you find it helpful. <a href="#" target="_blank">Say hello on Twitter.</a></div>' +
'    </div>' +
'</div>';


  // append a new element to the DOM
  jQuery('body').after('<div class="modal-dialog modal"></div>');

  // insert HTML dynamically
  jQuery(".modal-dialog").html(modalHtml);

  // display
  jQuery(".modal-dialog").modal('show');
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery --> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
<!-- BS JavaScript --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Hello Word</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Olá, obrigada pela ajuda mas quando testei deu este erro: jQuery(...).modal is not a function

Comment: verifique se você esta chamando os arquivos na sequencia correta Ex:    
 `<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- BS JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>`

Comment: Sim está tudo correto, mas continua a gerar esse erro :/

Comment: acredito que seja algo com seu jquery. Eu testei aqui e esta funcionando

Comment: Já funciona :) obrigada pela ajuda